# How to drag and drop 2D UI image on 3D Game object and then instantiate 3D game object at the position where we dropped Our 2D UI image?

Tags: user-interface, unity-game-engine, drag-and-drop

I have a cube in my scene so what I want is to drag and drop a 2d UI image of wrench tool over the cube and as soon as I drop that image on 3d cube the wrench prefab must be instantiated there.

Here is an image showing what I need

[image: drag and drop on cube]

I am using below code to drag my UI Image around the scene but dont know how to drop this on 3D Cube and instantiate a wrench prefab

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class wrench : MonoBehaviour {


    public bool Dragging = false;
    public bool collision = false;
    Vector3 position;

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {

    }

    public void BeginDrag(){
        position = gameObject.transform.position;
        Dragging = true;
    }

    public void Drag(){    
        transform.position = Input.mousePosition;
    }

    public void Drop(){
        if (!collision) {
            gameObject.transform.position = position;
        }
        Dragging = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

usually on stack overflow you should add some information about what you did and show some code so we can help figure out what is the problem in your approach. People won't write all the code for you without knowing what your project currently look like.

That being said, if you don't have anything to show yet and just wonder where to start, here are an idea:

You can get the position of the mouse in the world, and shoot a ray from it. Then check if this ray hits and object. like this:

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0))
{
    ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(Input.mousePosition);

    if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit))
    {
        Debug.Log(hit); // Find a way to figure out what object you hit
    }
}
```

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/fQVS9.jpg hey man please check this picture this is what i want

Comment: I know what you want, what did you code to try and do it? Can you do it with the idea I gave in my answer? You need to try coding something

Comment: i simple written a code which is dragging this UI Image around the 3d scene now what i want is that how to drop that image on that cube and instantiate a wrench prefab let me show u the code of dragging

Comment: please check my question i have added a code i use this code to dragging this ui image around the scene

Comment: Do you understand the code I put in my answer? Just use something like it in your drop function. To create the prefab, use `Instantiate`.